# Double UDP socket binding in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, udp, sockets

In C++, when I run (red alert! pseudo-code)

```
bind(s1, <local address:port1234>)
bind(s2, <local address:port1234>)
```

on two different UDP sockets (`s1` and `s2` each created with a call to `socket()`) I get problems. In Linux (Ubuntu), the double binding seems to be fine. In Windows, however, the double binding fails, and the call to `bind()` the second time for the same address returns `!= 0`.

I want to get the behavior I have on Windows on my Linux machine. Are there some settings I can work to get a "port busy" on Linux?

Comment: Can you post real code? Until you asked I was pretty sure you *do* get an error the second time you bind.

Comment: I thought so too, so I tested it. After the socket() call, the second bind() to the same port returns EADDRINUSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [bind](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html) and [setsockopt](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/setsockopt.html). Unless you have invoked setsockopt with SO_REUSEADDR, then your invocation of bind with the same address should result in failure with EADDRINUSE.

Comment: You're right on the money! SO_REUSEADDR doesn't work the same way in Windows and Linux (BSD-sockets?).

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR doesn't let you bind to an endpoint twice, though. Its purpose is to override the TIME_WAIT state after you close a TCP socket. Normally the OS keeps a TCP socket in TIME_WAIT for a few minutes to pick up any "late" packets that haven't arrived yet. If you try to open a new socket you get EADDRINUSE unless you specify SO_REUSEADDR which kills the TIME_WAIT socket.

Comment: @JohnKugelman- actually not true; on Linux and for UDP, SO_REUSEADDR actually does let you have multiple sockets bound to the same endpoint at the same time. This is different from the semantics for Linux+TCP and also different from the semantics on BSD.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the behaviour I get on Linux.  When I run the following test program, the second `bind` call fails with `EADDRINUSE`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int s1, s2;
    struct sockaddr_in sa = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port = 0x5555,
        .sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY };

    s1 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    s2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (bind(s1, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) < 0)
        perror("bind 1");
    if (bind(s2, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) < 0)
        perror("bind 2");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for code example (I was about to post one, but won't now :-P), but a small nit: `AF_INET` should be used for the address family (i.e., in the `sin_family` field).

Comment: Personally I use `AF_INET` in the `socket` call too---the Open Group Base Specification doesn't actually have any `PF_*` constants---but I can see more of a case for "lenience" for `socket` and other non-address usages.

Comment: Right you are sir, updated (the Linux man pages say to use the `PF_` constants for the argument to `socket()`, but I'm sure there's no practical difference).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that?  According to `man 7 ip` on my Linux box (fedora 9):

> When a process wants to receive new incoming packets or connections, it should bind a socket to a local interface address using bind(2).   *Only one  IP  socket  may  be bound to any given local (address, port) pair.*

There is no mention of an exception for UDP binding in either `man 7 ip` or `man 7 udp`.  (This does not prove anything, but non-documented behaviour in something as basic as this is ... surprising.)