# What is the difference between AF_INET and PF_INET constants?

Tags: python, c, unix, sockets

Looking at examples about socket programming, we can see that some people use `AF_INET` while others use `PF_INET`. In addition, sometimes [both of them are used at the same example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384562/double-udp-socket-binding-in-linux/2384605#2384605). The question is: Is there any difference between them? Which one should we use?

If you can answer that, another question would be... Why there are these two similar (but equal) constants?

---

### What I've discovered, so far:

#### The `socket` manpage

In (Unix) socket programming, we have the `socket()` function that receives the following parameters:

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

The manpage says:

> The `domain` argument specifies a communication domain; this selects  the
>   protocol  family  which will be used for communication.  These families
>   are  defined  in  <sys/socket.h>.

And the manpage cites `AF_INET` as well as some other `AF_` constants for the `domain` parameter. Also, at the `NOTES` section of the same manpage, we can read:

> The manifest constants used under 4.x BSD  for  protocol  families  are
>   PF_UNIX,  PF_INET,  etc., while AF_UNIX etc. are used for address families.
>   However, already the BSD man page promises: "The protocol family
>   generally  is the same as the address family", and subsequent standards
>   use AF_* everywhere.

#### The C headers

The `sys/socket.h` does not actually define those constants, but instead includes `bits/socket.h`. This file defines around 38 `AF_` constants and 38 `PF_` constants like this:

```
#define PF_INET     2   /* IP protocol family.  */
#define AF_INET     PF_INET
```

#### Python

The [Python socket module](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) is very similar to the C API. However, there are many `AF_` constants but only one `PF_` constant (PF_PACKET). Thus, in Python we have no choice but use `AF_INET`.

I think this decision to include only the `AF_` constants follows one of the guiding principles: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." [(The Zen of Python)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

#### Other info

[This forum post](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showpost.php?p=17391&postcount=5) links to [this old message](http://www.kohala.com/start/lanciani.96apr10.txt), which contains some historical information.

Comment: See also this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729366/what-is-the-difference-between-af-inet-and-pf-inet-in-socket-programming

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the [Wikipedia notes on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Protocol_and_address_families) sum it up pretty well:

> The original design concept of the socket interface distinguished between protocol types (families) and the specific address types that each may use. It was envisioned that a protocol family may have several address types. Address types were defined by additional symbolic constants, using the prefix `AF_` instead of `PF_`. The `AF_`-identifiers are intended for all data structures that specifically deal with the address type and not the protocol family. However, this concept of separation of protocol and address type has not found implementation support and the `AF_`-constants were simply defined by the corresponding protocol identifier, rendering the distinction between `AF_` versus `PF_` constants a technical argument of no significant practical consequence. Indeed, much confusion exists in the proper usage of both forms.

Even if someone came up with a reason to have a difference today, they'd have to come up with new identifiers or so much stuff would break...

Comment: In short, it's flaw of design by the mortal. We have to live with it.