# What is the difference between AF_INET and PF_INET in socket programming?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

What is the difference between AF_INET and PF_INET in socket programming?

I'm confused between using AF_INET and PF_INET in `socket()` and `bind()`.

Also, how to give ip-address in `sin_addr` field?

Comment: Just search the net: one result is [this](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/563350)

Comment: I've been wondering this as well.  They seem to get used interchangeably in the socket call among different coders.

Comment: @MattH They both are same as per the new Linux Kernels. You can find the same in Duke's answer below.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

[Beej's famous network programming guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#system-calls-or-bust) gives a nice explanation:

> In some documentation, you'll see mention of a mystical "PF_INET".
>   This is a weird etherial beast that is rarely seen in nature, but I
>   might as well clarify it a bit here. Once a long time ago, it was
>   thought that maybe a address family (what the "AF" in "AF_INET" stands
>   for) might support several protocols that were referenced by their
>   protocol family (what the "PF" in "PF_INET" stands for).
>   That didn't happen. Oh well. So the correct thing to do is to use AF_INET in your
>   struct sockaddr_in and PF_INET in your call to socket(). But
>   practically speaking, you can use AF_INET everywhere. And, since
>   that's what W. Richard Stevens does in his book, that's what I'll do
>   here.

Answer (score 92):

I found in Linux kernel source code that PF_INET and AF_INET are the same.
The following code is from file **include/linux/socket.h**, line 204 of Linux kernel 3.2.21 tree.

```
/* Protocol families, same as address families. */
...
#define PF_INET     AF_INET
```

Comment: sure Duke, is it same for previous kernels also , i mean kernels prior to version 3.0 ?

Comment: As fas as I know, in all versions of kernel and libc, PF_* == AF_*

Comment: Is this true on non-linux platforms?

Comment: I think to make sure, you need to check the included header file :)

Comment: On Ubuntu/Debian I found AF definitions in `/usr/src/linux-headers-<kernel_version>/include/linux/socket.h`

Answer (score 60):

- AF = Address Family
- PF = Protocol Family

Meaning, `AF_INET` refers to addresses from the internet, IP addresses specifically. `PF_INET` refers to anything in the protocol, usually sockets/ports.

Consider reading the man pages for [socket(2)](http://man.cx/socket%282%29) and [bind(2)](http://man.cx/bind%282%29). For the `sin_addr` field, just do something like the following to set it:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr);
```

Comment: thanks @codemac , i have used addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); but what is inet_pton() for ?

Comment: also for man pages, when i type man bind(2) or man bind() , terminal gives unexpected token '(' error whereas man bind gives explanation of bind in bash builtins. How to get man page for bind() . i mean bind() function ?

Comment: @jatt.beas: The syntax is `man <section> <topic>`, e.g. `man 2 bind`.

Answer (score 15):

In fact, AF_ and PF_ are the same thing. There are some words on Wikipedia will clear your confusion

> The original design concept of the socket interface distinguished between protocol types (families) and the specific address types that each may use. It was envisioned that a protocol family may have several address types. Address types were defined by additional symbolic constants, using the prefix AF_ instead of PF_. The AF_-identifiers are intended for all data structures that specifically deal with the address type and not the protocol family. However, this concept of separation of protocol and address type has not found implementation support and the AF_-constants were simply defined by the corresponding protocol identifier, rendering the distinction between AF_ versus PF_ constants a technical argument of no significant practical consequence. Indeed, much confusion exists in the proper usage of both forms.

Answer (score 9):

AF_INET = Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses

PF_INET = Packet Format, Internet = IP, TCP/IP or UDP/IP

AF_INET is the address family that is used for the socket you're creating (in this case an Internet Protocol address). The Linux kernel, for example, supports 29 other address families such as UNIX sockets and IPX, and also communications with IRDA and Bluetooth (AF_IRDA and AF_BLUETOOTH, but it is doubtful you'll use these at such a low level).

For the most part sticking with AF_INET for socket programming over a network is the safest option.

Meaning, AF_INET refers to addresses from the internet, IP addresses specifically.

PF_INET refers to anything in the protocol, usually sockets/ports.

Comment: It must be pointed out that the correct expansion of AF/PF is "Address/Packet *Family*" (as in the other answers), not "Format" as you have here. I realise its very possible that you've always known that, and intentionally chose the (technically incorrect) expansion "Format", because you think it has a pedagogical advantage over "Family"–you could well be right there, but if that's your reasoning, it might be better to state so explicitly, so people don't come away from your answer mistakenly thinking "Address/Protocol Format" is the proper terminology

Comment: @SimonKissane Do you mean _Protocol Family_ instead of _Packet Family_?

Comment: @Torin yes you are right. I was pointing out the "Format" bit is wrong, but indeed the "Packet" bit is wrong as well. I said it right the second time, the first time I copied the answer's mistake without noticing it

Answer (score 7):

Checking the header file solve's the problem.
One can check for there system compiler.

For my system , AF_INET == PF_INET

AF == Address Family  And PF == Protocol Family

Protocol families, same as address families.

[image]

Comment: `/usr/src/linux-headers-X.X.X-XX-generic/include/linux/socket.h`

Answer (score 2):

There are situations where it matters.

If you pass AF_INET to `socket()` in Cygwin, your socket may or may not be randomly reset. Passing PF_INET ensures that the connection works right.

Cygwin is self-admittedly a huge mess for socket programming, but it *is* a real world case where AF_INET and PF_INET are not identical.

Comment: Please explain. I find `#define PF_INET         AF_INET` in Cygwin's `socket.h`.

Comment: I think this answer is just wrong. In Cygwin, "PF_INET=AF_INET". Cygwin is just a layer over Winsock2 anyway, also in which "PF_INET=AF_INET". Sometimes a person has a weird problem they don't understand, and it goes away when they change something, which convinces them the change fixed it – when in reality the change was a no-op, and the problem coincidentally went away for unrelated reasons. I suspect that's what must have happened to give you this false belief. As far as I am aware, in all real systems ever, PF_X=AF_X, for all values of X