# Winsock Error After Client Connection 10038

Tags: c++, sockets, server, putty, winsock

I'm new to Winsock. I have an error that appears at some point mentioned in `Main.cpp`.

While testing with PuTTy, the client connects to the server, and then the PuTTy window immediately closes.

`WSAGetLastError()` says 10038 (i.e. an action on a non-socket). For some reason, it appears after the `accept()` call, when I try to `recv()` data from the socket returned by `accept()`.

Here the source code:

(it will compile, I'm using PuTTy as the client for testing, also add `WS2_32.LIB` as input)

Main.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace Nikson;

void main() {
    Sock listen(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    Sock client;

    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;*/
    SockAddr sa(AF_INET, 53000, INADDR_ANY),bb;

    listen.Bind(sa);
    listen.Listen();    

    client = listen.Accept(bb);
    // **AFTER THIS CLIENT CONNECTS BUT THEN DISCONNECTS**

    listen.Close();
    std::cout << "Connected " << client.GetID() << WSAGetLastError();

    char buf[4096];
    int size;
    while (true) {

        size = client.Recv(buf, sizeof buf, 0);

        std::cout << WSAGetLastError();
        std::cin.get();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            std::cout << buf[i];
    }
}
```

The program uses a library written by me, which wraps a Winsock `SOCKET` as a class:

Sock.h

```
#pragma once
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include "SockAddr.h"

namespace Nikson {
    class Sock
    {
    public:
        Sock();
        Sock(int af, int type, int protocol);
        Sock(const SOCKET& base);
        ~Sock();
        int Bind(const SockAddr& sa);

        int Send(const char* buf,
            int len,
            int flags);
        int Recv(char* buf,
            int len,
            int flags);

        int Listen();
        Nikson::Sock Accept(const SockAddr& sa);

        int Connect(const SockAddr& sa);
        int Close();
        int Shutdown(int how);
        SOCKET GetID();
    private:
        SOCKET m_NativeID;
        static inline WSAData s_WSAData;
        static inline int s_SockCount=0;
    };
}
```

Sock.cpp

```
#include "Sock.h"
#include <iostream>

//int Nikson::Sock::s_SockCount = 0;

Nikson::Sock::Sock()
{
    if (s_SockCount == 0) 
    {
        WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        if ( WSAStartup(ver, &s_WSAData)!= 0) {
            std::cout << "Cant Init winsock! Quiting" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    ++s_SockCount;
}

Nikson::Sock::Sock(int af,int type, int protocol)
{
    if (s_SockCount == 0)
    {
        WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        if (WSAStartup(ver, &s_WSAData) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Cant Init winsock! Quiting" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    ++s_SockCount;
    m_NativeID = socket(af, type, protocol);

    if (m_NativeID == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "Invalid socket";
    }
}

Nikson::Sock::Sock(const SOCKET& base)
{
    if (s_SockCount == 0)
    {
        WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        if (WSAStartup(ver, &s_WSAData) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Cant Init winsock! Quiting" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    ++s_SockCount;
    m_NativeID = base;
}

Nikson::Sock::~Sock()
{
    closesocket(m_NativeID);
    --s_SockCount;
    if (s_SockCount == 0) {
        WSACleanup();
    }
}

int Nikson::Sock::Bind(const SockAddr& sa)
{
    return bind(m_NativeID, (sockaddr*)&sa.data, sizeof(sa.data));
}

int Nikson::Sock::Send(const char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    return send(m_NativeID,buf,len,flags);
}

int Nikson::Sock::Recv(char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    return recv(m_NativeID,buf,len,flags);
}

int Nikson::Sock::Listen()
{
    return listen(m_NativeID, SOMAXCONN);
}

Nikson::Sock Nikson::Sock::Accept(const SockAddr& sa)
{
    int size = sizeof(sa);
    return Nikson::Sock(accept(m_NativeID,(sockaddr*)&sa.data,&size));
}

int Nikson::Sock::Connect(const SockAddr& sa)
{
    return connect(m_NativeID, (sockaddr*)&sa.data, sizeof(sa));
}

int Nikson::Sock::Close()
{
    return closesocket(m_NativeID);
}

int Nikson::Sock::Shutdown(int how)
{
    return shutdown(m_NativeID,how);
}

SOCKET Nikson::Sock::GetID()
{
    return m_NativeID;
}
```

SockAddr.h

```
#pragma once
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

namespace Nikson {
    struct SockAddr
    {
        SockAddr() = default;
        SockAddr(int family, int port, const std::string& ip);
        SockAddr(int family, int port, unsigned long ip);
        sockaddr_in data;
    };
}
```

SockAddr.cpp

```
#include "SockAddr.h"

Nikson::SockAddr::SockAddr(int family, int port, const std::string& ip)
{
    ZeroMemory(this, sizeof * this);

    data.sin_family = family;
    data.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(family, ip.c_str(), &(data.sin_addr));
}

Nikson::SockAddr::SockAddr(int family, int port, unsigned long ip)
{
    /*ZeroMemory(this, sizeof * this);*/
    data.sin_family = family;
    data.sin_port = htons(port);
    data.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ip;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This code does not use my library classes, and works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <thread>
#pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void main() 
{
    //Initialize windsock
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsok = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsok != 0) {
        cerr << "Cant Init winsock! Quiting" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //Create a socket
    
    SOCKETlistening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Cant crerate a socket, Quiting" << endl;
    }

    //Bind the  an ip adress and port to socket
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;//could also use inet_pton.....

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    // Tell winsock the socket is for listening
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    // wait for connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);
    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){}

    //char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    //char service[NI_MAXHOST];
    //ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    //ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXHOST);

    //if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0) {
    //  cout << host << " connected on port" << service << std::endl;
    //}
    //else {
    //  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
    //  cout << host<<" connected on port "<<ntohs(client.sin_port)<<endl;
    //}// close listening socket

    closesocket(listening);

    // while loop: accept and echo message back to client
    bool running = true;
    auto reciver = [&clientSocket,&running]() {
        char buf[4096];
        while(running) {
            ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
            int byteRecived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < byteRecived; ++i) {
                cout << buf[i];
            }
            cout << "\n";
            if (byteRecived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                cerr << "recv() error";
                break;
            }
            if (byteRecived == 0) {
                cerr << "CLient disconnected";
                break;
            }
        }
        running = false;
    };

    string letter;
    
    thread listener(reciver);
    while (running){
        letter = "";
        cin >> letter;
        letter += "\n";
        send(clientSocket, letter.data(), letter.size(), 0);

    }

    //close the socket
    closesocket(clientSocket);

    //Shutdown winsock
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Have some patience, you just posted this question an hour ago. It takes time for people to see it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Hello, Thank you for your respond! I`ve modified my code, but PuTTy still can connect but immediately disconnects. Its weird, beacause the same code written without my abstraction class works just fine, i added it to my post. Also i fogot to mention: To connect winsock api i added ws2_32.lib as input in linker settings

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried my SockAddr in the code from the addition, it works fine. Threfore im assuming the problem must be in Sock class, but idk where

Answer (score 2):

Your `Sock` class lacks proper *copy/move semantics*.

When copying a `Sock` object to another `Sock`, you are not managing your `s_SockCount` refcount, and more importantly you are not **duplicating** the socket that `m_NativeID` refers to.

Since `m_NativeID` refers to an OS-allocated `SOCKET` resource, the default compiler-generated copy/move semantics are NOT sufficient to manage the socket correctly.

`Sock::Accept()` returns a *temporary* `Sock` object. When that object goes out of scope, its destructor closes the socket that `m_NativeID` refers to.

The statement `client = listen.Accept(bb);` will *copy/move* that temporary `Sock` object to `client`, and then immediately destroy the temporary object.  Without valid copy/move semantics implemented in `Sock`, the default behavior will cause both `Sock` objects to refer to the same socket.

So, when the temporary `Sock` object is destroyed, it closes the socket, leaving `client` referring to an invalid socket.  That is why you are getting the `10038` (`WSAENOTSOCK`) error on operations performed on `client`.

To fix this, you need to add copy/move semantics to your `Sock` class, eg:

```
class Sock
{
public:
    Sock();
    Sock(int af, int type, int protocol);
    Sock(SOCKET base); // <-- remove const reference!
    Sock(const Sock &src); // <-- add this!
    Sock(Sock&& src); // <-- add this!
    ...
    Sock& operator=(Sock rhs); // <-- add this!
    ...
};
```

```
Nikson::Sock::Sock()
    : m_NativeID(INVALID_SOCKET) // <-- add this!
{
    // init WSA, increment s_SockCount ...
}

Nikson::Sock::Sock(int af, int type, int protocol)
    : m_NativeID(INVALID_SOCKET) // <-- add this!
{
    // init WSA, increment s_SockCount ...
    // create socket ...
}

Nikson::Sock::Sock(SOCKET base)
    : m_NativeID(base) // <-- add this!
{
    // init WSA, increment s_SockCount ...
    //m_NativeID = base; // <-- remove this!
}

// add this!
Nikson::Sock::Sock(const Sock& base)
    : m_NativeID(INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // init WSA, increment s_SockCount ...

    if (base.m_NativeID != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        WSAPROTOCOL_INFO info = {};
        if (WSADuplicateSocket(base.m_NativeID, GetCurrentProcessId(), &info) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Cant duplicate socket!" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        m_NativeID = WSASocket(FROM_PROTOCOL_INFO, FROM_PROTOCOL_INFO, FROM_PROTOCOL_INFO, &info, 0, 0);
        if (m_NativeID == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cout << "Invalid socket";
        }
    }
}

// add this!
Nikson::Sock::Sock(Sock&& base)
    : m_NativeID(INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // init WSA, increment s_SockCount ...

    m_NativeID = base.m_NativeID;
    base.m_NativeID = INVALID_SOCKET;
}

Nikson::Sock::~Sock()
{
    //closesocket(m_NativeID); // <-- replace this...
    Close();                   // <-- with this!

    // decrement s_SockCount, cleanup WSA ...
}

...

int Nikson::Sock::Close()
{
    int ret = closesocket(m_NativeID);
    m_NativeID = INVALID_SOCKET; // <-- add this!
    return ret;
}

...

// add this!
Nikson::Sock& Nikson::Sock::operator=(Sock rhs)
{
    std::swap(m_NativeID, rhs.m_NativeID);
    return *this;
}
```

---

On a side note, there are some other problems with your code:

- `PF_INET` should be `AF_INET`.
- Your `Sock` constructors are not initializing `m_NativeID` if something goes wrong. See fixes above.
- `Sock::Bind()` and `Sock::Connect()` are casting away `const`ness they shouldn't be. `bind()` and `connect()` expect a `const sockaddr*`.  You are also passing the wrong `size` value:

  ```
  int Nikson::Sock::Bind(const SockAddr& sa)
  {
     return bind(m_NativeID, (const sockaddr*)&sa.data, sizeof(sa.data));
  }

  int Nikson::Sock::Connect(const SockAddr& sa)
  {
    return connect(m_NativeID, (const sockaddr*)&sa.data, sizeof(sa.data));
  }
  ```
- `Sock::Accept()` is modifying a `const` object, which is *undefined behavior*. `accept()` takes a non-const `sockaddr*`, because it modifies the `sockaddr` it is given, but you have that wrapped inside a `const SockAddr` object. You need to drop the `const`, so the caller can actually receive the client's info.  You are also setting `size` to the wrong value:

  ```
  Nikson::Sock Nikson::Sock::Accept(SockAddr& sa)
  {
    int size = sizeof(sa.data);
    return Sock(accept(m_NativeID, (sockaddr*) &sa.data, &size));
  }
  ```

  You might also consider overloading `Sock::Accept()` to let the `SockAddr` be optional, if the caller doesn't want it:

  ```
  Nikson::Sock Nikson::Sock::Accept()
  {
    return Sock(accept(m_NativeID, NULL, NULL));
  }
  ```
- `Sock::Close()` is not setting the `m_NativeID` member to `INVALID_SOCKET`. You are allowing a `Sock` to be closed before it is destroyed, but you need to make sure the destructor can still act properly. Calling `closesocket()` on a `SOCKET` that is not `INVALID_SOCKET` but doesn't refer to a valid socket is *undefined behavior*. See fix above.
- Your `SockAddr` class only supports `sockaddr_in` (`AF_INET`), so it doesn't really make sense to let callers set its `family` value. Just hard-code it instead.  On the other hand, if you want to support both `AF_INET` (IPv4) and `AF_INET6` (IPv6) IP addresses, you need to change the `data` member to `sockaddr_storage` instead, and then cast it to `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` as needed.
- I would strongly suggest moving the calls to `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` into a separate class, and then create an instance of that class at the top of `main()` before doing anything else with your `Sock` class.  Those function calls really don't belong in the `Sock` class itself.

Comment: Remy, it works! Thank you a lot, i really appreciate how detailed those example are. Also I find out that i didnt differ `intialization` from `asighning`, which is really important.  I have a qustion left about `PF_INET`:  isnt it the same as `AF_INET`?

Comment: Could you tell what book you used to learn winsock. Is there any youd recommend? The only src about ws i found is `beej's guide to network programming`. Isnt it a good foundation

Comment: @Maykusa "*isnt [PF_INET] the same as AF_INET?*" - see [What is the difference between AF_INET and PF_INET in socket programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729366/). "*Could you tell what book you used to learn winsock*" - I didn't use any book. I only used Microsoft's online documentation, studied other people's code, and practiced with my own code. But there are plenty of good books available on socket/Winsock programming. And no, I don't have any recommendations.

Comment: I had an issue similar to OP's one but I was writing a multi-platform program for both Linux and Windows. Turns out I was casting windows SOCKET type into int somewhere and recv was returning 10038 error. Your response helped me figured that out.